# Tengo un error que dice " incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Libro "

Tags: java

El error aparece en la línea que dice **Libro n = darCatalogo().get(i);**

Tengo 4 clases en el proyecto, pero en este caso solo necesito la Clase Libro y la clase TiendaLibros

Clase Libro

```
public class Libro {

    /** Título del libro */
    private String titulo;

    /** ISBN del libro */
    private String isbn;

    /** Precio del libro */
    private int precio;
/**
     * Crea el libro con su información básica: título, ISBN y precio.
     * @param unTitulo Título del libro. unTitulo!= null.
     * @param unISBN ISBN del libro. unISBN != null.
     * @param unPrecio Precio del libro. unPrecio >= 0.
     */
    public Libro( String unTitulo, String unISBN, int unPrecio ) {
        titulo = unTitulo;
        isbn = unISBN;
        precio = unPrecio;
    }
    public String getISBN() {
        return isbn;
    }
```

Clase TiendaLibros

```
public class TiendaLibros {

    /**
     * Catálogo o lista de libros
     */
    private ArrayList catalogo;

    /**
     * Carro de compras de los libros
     */
    private CarroCompras carrito;

    /**
     * Crea la tienda de libros con el catálogo de libros vacío
     */
    public TiendaLibros() {
        catalogo = new ArrayList( );
        carrito = new CarroCompras( );
    }
/**
     * Adiciona un nuevo libro al catálogo de la tienda. <br>
     * <b>post: </b> Se agregó un libro al catálogo.
     * @param nuevoLibro Nuevo libro del catálogo. nuevoLibro != null.
     */
    public void adicionarLibroCatalogo( Libro nuevoLibro ) {
        catalogo.add(nuevoLibro);
    }
/**
     * Adiciona un nuevo libro al catálogo de la tienda. <br>
     * <b>post: </b> Se agregó un libro al catálogo.
     * @param nuevoLibro Nuevo libro del catálogo. nuevoLibro != null.
     */
    public void adicionarLibroCatalogo( Libro nuevoLibro ) {
        catalogo.add(nuevoLibro);
    }
    public ArrayList darCatalogo() {
        return catalogo;
    }
/**
     * Retorna si existe un libro del catálogo de la tienda con el ISBN dado.
     * @param isbn ISBN del libro que se quiere buscar en el catálogo.
     * @return libro Libro encontrado en el catalogo o null si no existe.
     */
    public Libro buscarLibro( String isbn ) {

        for(int i=0; i<catalogo.size();i++)
        {
            Libro n = darCatalogo().get(i);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

como dije en el titulo y descripción, me da un error **" incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Libro "** en la clase TiendaLibros en el método buscarLibros en la línea de código de **Libro n = darCatalogo().get(i);** en especifico me aparece en la **i** la marca roja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo indica el error, y es que get devuelve un objeto y no un tipo de clase Libro. Por lo que debes hacer un cast.

```
public Libro buscarLibro( String isbn ) {

    for(int i=0; i<catalogo.size();i++)
    {
        Libro n = (Libro)darCatalogo().get(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```